# SQLAlchemy Filter only minimum field value from distinct pairs

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a `ProductPurchase` model that describes purchase made by the `client`.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import DateTime
from sqlalchemy import String

Base = declarative_base()


class ProductPurchase(Base):
   __tablename__ = "product_client"
   
   client_id = Column(String(255))
   product_id = Column(String(255))
   purchased_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True))
```

What I want to do is get the list of `ProductPurchase` where I would only have the first purchase of a `client` for given `product_id`.
For example:

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| client_id | product_id | purchased_at |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| c1        | prod1      | 2020-01-01   |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| c1        | prod1      | 2020-01-02   |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| c2        | prod1      | 2020-01-01   |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| c2        | prod2      | 2020-01-01   |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

I want to get following rows:

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| client_id | product_id | purchased_at |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| c1        | prod1      | 2020-01-01   |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| c2        | prod1      | 2020-01-01   |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| c2        | prod2      | 2020-01-01   |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

Note that `client_id=1` and `product_id=1` pair is missing for date `2020-01-02` because it should be filtered out - the goal is to obtain only the first purchase of the product by the client.
How can I attempt this using `sqlalchemy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in SQLAlchemy you can use groupy by client_id and product_id and take minimum of purchased_at.

Something like this

```
from sqlalchemy import func

session.query(ProductPurchase.client_id ,ProductPurchase.purchased_id , func.min(ProductPurchase.purchased_at)).group_by(ProductPurchase.client_id ,ProductPurchase.purchased_id).all()
```

Comment: That's simple and what I was looking for, thank you

Answer (score 0):

here is the sql code , sqlachemy support all over() and PArition by statement as well as using of cte , just follow the sqlachemy docs:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
   *
  , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY p.client_id , p.product_id ORDER BY p.purchased_at ASC) rnk
 FROM 
product AS p
)

SELECT cte.client_id
     , cte.product_id
     , cte.purchased_at
FROM cte
WHERE cte.rnk = 1
```